# changing datetime to date and fetch data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table where the fileuploaded time is stored as datetime variable and it talble the values are like 2013-12-15 22:30:00.030.

How can I fetch the data of record that are uploaded between two dates using, excluding the time.
Because if I use the below command I am getting errors

```
select * from story where DateCreated ='2013-12-15'(not working)
select * from story where DateCreated ='2013-12-15 22:30:00.030' (working but I don't want to specify time)
```

I want a query something like this :

```
select * from story where DateCreated ='2013-12-15'
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: i am using sqlserver 2012. there is no error ,the query is actually asking for the whole date and time. but if  give only date there are no rows comming

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get records for specified day it will help you:

```
`select * from story where DateCreated>=DATE('2013-12-15 22:30:00.030') and DateCreated<DATE_ADD(DATE('2013-12-15 22:30:00.030'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`
```

Comment: but how can i use the same if the datecreaed is stored as 2013-12-15 22:30:00.030  while createing the query i have to get rid of the time

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your database implementation has something to convert a date/time combination to a date.  For example in MySQL, you could do

`select * from story where date(DateCreated) ='2013-12-15'`

Comment: Terrible advice. It'll slow as hell.
Never do this. Never.
It'll need to apply DATE() to ALL records in the table

Comment: I saw your example, it looks like that will do better. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: @syabro since this is for SQL Server it is not all that bad. Have a look at this question on DBA. [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query only on the date portion of a datetime column, you can cast the column to type date in the select:

```
select * from story where CAST(DateCreated As Date) ='2013-12-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check if the file is uploaded in a specific interval, for example on 15 dec 2013:

```
select * from story
WHERE DateCreated >= CAST('20131215' AS DATETIME)
AND   DateCreated < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST('20131215' AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 0):

Date functions generally don't take advantage of indexes (as pointed out in other answers) so something like the following would be better.

Instead of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   story 
WHERE  datecreated = '2013-12-15'
```

Use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   story 
WHERE  datecreated >= '2013-12-15' 
       AND datecreated < '2013-12-16'
```